# How to capture css3 animation iteration if alternate

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, css-animations, keyframe

I'm developing a small application based on css3 animation with keyframes. I'm interested only in Chrome behavior. I can use jQuery or vanilla Javascript.

If I set an animation "infinite" along with "alternate" property on an element, the event `animationiteration` is fired two times before reaching the initial state of the element, since the iteration is counted even when the animation "reverses" itself.

The only solution I came up, to know when the initial state is reached, is to track the iteration with a variable:

CSS example:

```
.animate{
    -webkit-animation: k-wide 0.6s ease-in infinite alternate;
    animation: k-wide 0.6s ease-in infinite alternate;
}
@-webkit-keyframes k-wide{
    from { transform: scale(1); }
    to { transform: scale(1.2); }
}
@keyframes k-wide{
    from { transform: scale(1); }
    to { transform: scale(1.2); }
}
```

Javascript example:

```
var initialState = true;

elem = $('#myAnimatedElem')
    //event listener
    .on('webkitAnimationIteration animationiteration',function(){
        initialState = !initialState ;
        if (initialState) runMyCustomScript();
    })
    //start animation
    .addClass('animate');
```

The question is: is there another method to catch the initial state? Is there a more efficient one? I was wondering if I missed some event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, no, you can't.

Alternatives:

1) Remove alternate from the animation. Make it alternate using more keyframes

```
@-webkit-keyframes k-wide {
    from { transform: scale(1); }
    50% { transform: scale(1.2); }
    to { transform: scale(1); }
}
```

2)  Use timeelapsed from the event and do some math.

Note that in the first alternative, the timing function is preserved.

from the [standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#animation-timing-function)

> For a keyframed animation, the ‘animation-timing-function’ applies
>   between keyframes, not over the entire animation. For example, in the
>   case of an ‘ease-in-out’ timing function, an animation will ease in at
>   the start of the keyframe and ease out at the end of the keyframe. An
>   ‘animation-timing-function’ defined within a keyframe block applies to
>   that keyframe, otherwise the timing function specified for the
>   animation is used.

In the following demo, an alternate animation moves the red box. An independent, single animation, move the shadow around it. 
Notice that the second part of the animation needs to have an ease-out (because the original is *reversed*

```css
.base {
  width: 400px;
  height: 800px;
  border: solid 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}

.move {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid 1px lightgreen;
  -webkit-animation: move 10s infinite linear;
  animation: move 10s infinite linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
  from {top: 0px;}
  to {top: 100%;}
}
@keyframes move {
  from {top: 0px;}
  to {top: 100%;}
}

.test1, .test2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 100%;
}

.test1 {
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-animation: test1 5s infinite ease-in alternate;
  animation: test1 5s infinite ease-in alternate;
}

.test2 {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px blue;
  -webkit-animation: test2 10s infinite ease-in;
  animation: test2 10s infinite ease-in;
}

@-webkit-keyframes test1 {
  from {left: 0px;}
  to {left: 100%;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes test2 {
  from {left: 0px;}
  50% {left: 100%;  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;} 
  to {left: 0px;}
}

@keyframes test1 {
  from {left: 0px;}
  to {left: 100%;}
}

@keyframes test2 {
  from {left: 0px;}
  50% {left: 100%;  animation-timing-function: ease-out;} 
  to {left: 0px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="base">
<div class="move">
<div class="test1"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="base" id="base2">
<div class="move">
<div class="test2"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah, this may works only for linear animation, but for an ease effect this is just wrong. I could use math to create a series of mathematically determined points between `0%` - `50%` - `100%` (specular from 50% to 100%), but it isn't a real ease, and more important, it isn't better in term of performace (and time spent to do this eheh). anyway thank you!

Comment: Probably your first approach is the best, I am just explaining the posible alternatives. Anyway, you don't any anything to replicate the ease, it's already there. see my edit

Comment: ok, I see. sorry but i don't understand the last phrase. the easing function is from a % to the next % (eg. 0%-20%). You can check my attempt in this [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ocy13kh9/7/). by the way, you already answered me saying _there's not a better method than the one I exposed_, so I assume this is the best answer!

Comment: It's not surprising that you didn't understand my comment. I don't even understand it myself...   Added an example; I meant that you don't need math for this, the function is available. (Namely, the ease-out)